# Get relation of ManyToMany entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I stuck with getting ManyToMany relation. I have two entities `Offer` and `OfferType`.
I defined ManyToMany relation only on `OfferEntity` and it looks like saving offers with multiple `OfferType` works fine in database I see correct joining table.

> OfferEntity.php

```
/**
 * Offer Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="offer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProjectBundle\Repository\OfferRepository")
 */
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = "1",
     *      minMessage = "You must specify at least one offer type."
     * )
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="OfferType")
     */
    private $types;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->types = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getTypes()
    {
        return $this->types;
    }

(...)
```

Right now, I would like to get all `types` assigned to the `offer`. I tried it like this:

```
// $offer is an Entity
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('offer.types')
    ->from('ProjectBundle:Offer', 'offer')
    ->where('offer = :offer')
    ->setParameters([
        'offer' => $offer
    ]);
```

Unfortunately I getting error:

```
[2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 13 near 'types FROM ProjectBundle:Offer': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a **StateFieldPathExpression**. 
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT offer.types FROM ProjectBundle:Offer offer WHERE offer = :offer
```

Based on StackOverflow answers for similar questions tried it also to use `IDENTITY()`:

```
// $offer is an Entity
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('IDENTITY(offer.types)')
    ->from('ProjectBundle:Offer', 'offer')
    ->where('offer = :offer')
    ->setParameters([
        'offer' => $offer
    ]);
```

But then I have:

```
[2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 22 near 'types) FROM ProjectBundle:Offer': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT IDENTITY(offer.types) FROM ProjectBundle:Offer offer WHERE offer = :offer
```

I would really appreciate any hints about getting ManyToMany relation, maybe my approach for this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not quite right. You need to join the entity you want to load. You should spend a bit more time reading the doctrine documentation on entity relations & querybuilder.

Like so.

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('offer', 'types')
    ->from('ProjectBundle:Offer', 'offer')
    ->join('offer.types', 'types')
    ->where('offer = :offer')
    ->setParameters([
        'offer' => $offer
    ]);
```

Then your result will contain what you want.

*Note*: you don't even *have* to join types to get types from an offer, you could also use

```
$offer->getTypes()
```

And types will lazy load in standard doctrine manner.

But querying it as above will load types in advance - so you avoid lazy loading. This may or may not be a better approach depending on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your many to many mappings set up only on one side, you'll only be able to query for the `Offer` and then retrieve the types from it:

```
$builder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('o', 't')
    ->from('ProjectBundle:Offer', 'o')
    ->join('o.types', 't')
    ->where('o.id = :offer')
    ->setParameter('offer', $offerId);

$offer = $builder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
$types = $offer->getTypes();
```

That was assuming you only had `$offerId` to work with. If you already have the whole `Offer` instance, you might just as well just call `getTypes()` on it and doctrine will take care of the rest.

If you were to define the inverse mappings on the `OfferType` entity like so:

```
class OfferType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Offer", mappedBy="types")
     */
    private $offers;
}
```

You could make queries for just the types:

```
$builder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t')
    ->from('ProjectBundle:OfferType', 't')
    ->join('t.offers', 'o')
    ->where('o = :offer')
    ->setParameter('offer', $offer);

$types = $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
```